# Integrate a 'My Maps' from Google Map's into a site and make the places searchable

Tags: google-maps, search, integration

I was wondering how to integrate one of 'My maps' into a site. I know there's an embed option but the idea was not only using all the places I added there but also make them searchable (by using a search box I guess).

Thanks in advance

---

Update: Found [this](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html) but I want to make it work with 'My maps'. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the Google Maps API. It offers much more flexibility than MyMaps.

Google Maps API Family: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

In particular, you might be interested in: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Using it requires a bit of knowledge of JavaScript, but it isn't too hard.

Developer's guide: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
Tutorial: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, using 'My Maps' was a requirement here. :S

Answer (score 1):

You have to do bit of server side scripting to make them searchable

First thing, is you need to define your centre of the map. Then add markers/location to the map and store their lat/lng values server side. When someone enters postcode/zip you need to use Geocode Google Maps API service to get lat/lng of the value entered, use it as a center, and then calculate distance using haversine formula to show nearest locations.

[Geocode API link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

[Haversine formula link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Thanks